# How should looks my pipe for filter through object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to create pipe for filtering my response.

I did something like this:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'filter',
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, input: string) {
        if (input) {
            input = input.toLowerCase();
            return value.filter(function (el: any) {
                return el.recipients.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1;
            })
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

But I got error:

```
ERROR TypeError: value.filter is not a function
    at FilterPipe.transform (FilterPipe.ts:10)
```

This my row

```
 <tr
    *ngFor="let r of recipients.recipients | FilterPipe: query | split; let i = index">
    <td>{{r}}</td>
```

and my input

```
<input class="form-control form-control-alternative" placeholder="Szukaj odbiorcy" type="text"
 [(ngModel)]="query">
```

My recipients output is:

```
 console.log('this.recipients ' +JSON.stringify(this.recipients));
```

> this.recipients {"recipients":"testee"}

How can I filter my object to get result?

Comment: If you changed the type of value to better reflect what you're actually getting, the compiler could help you a bit more.

Comment: jonrsharpe right, TS compiler doesn't know that value is Array, set its type at least any[] .

Comment: still nothing because recipients doesn't exist on type any[]

Comment: The value you're expecting isn't `any[]` either. You're passing an *object*, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

Array has `filter` method, but your `value` is type of object, so you've got the error:

> value.filter is not a function

So you need to convert your object into array:

```
transform(value: any, input: string) {
    if (input && typeof input ==='string') {
        input = input.toLowerCase();
        if (Array.isArray(value)) {
            return value.filter(function (el: any) {
                return el.recipients.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1;
            })
        } else if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
             const filtered = Object.entries(value)
                 .filter(([k, v])=> v.toLowerCase() === input.toLowerCase());
             return Object.fromEntries(filtered);
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

An example:

```js
    let obj = {"recipients":"testee", 'foo': 'bar'};
    let input = 'testee';
    const filtered = Object.entries(obj).filter(([k, v])=> v.toLowerCase() === input.toLowerCase());
    console.log(Object.fromEntries(filtered));
```

Comment: Property 'toLowerCase' does not exist on type 'unknown'.

Comment: I checked but it's still Property 'toLowerCase' does not exist on type 'unknown'.

Comment: @MarcinDomorozki it is really interesting situation. Could you create a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/). Without your data and code, it is hard to say what is going on.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fskvuu?file=src%2Fapp%2F_pipes%2Ffilter-pipe-recipients.pipe.ts

Comment: @MarcinDomorozki great! But you need to create a full example with reproduced error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213335/discussion-between-stepup-and-marcin-domorozki).

Answer (score 0):

1. You run on recipients.recipients via ngFor so it must be it Iterable (like Array) and I see that its string: "recipients":"tested".
2. In your pipe you already got each recipient so you need to change el.recipients.toLowerCase() to el.toLowerCase()